# How to access data in an array in order to call an API?

Tags: reactjs, api, map-function

I need to access a data inside an array from the response of the API (inside the result), because i need the ID value there to call another API. What could possibly wrong in my code that it shows an error?

Here is the object from the response of the API.

```
data: {page: 1, results: Array(7), total_pages: 1, total_results: 7}
headers: {cache-control: 'max-age=0, private, must-revalidate', content-type: 'application/json;charset=utf-8', etag: 'W/"6e36062c2e4d1dd119fceb30d730158c"'}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: null, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

```
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { API_KEY } from "./Constants";

const MovieList = () => {
  //   const [data, setData] = useState();
  useEffect(() => {
    axios({
      method: "get",
      url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/account/{account_id}/lists?api_key=${API_KEY}&session_id=${localStorage.getItem(
        "sessionID"
      )}`,
    })
      .then((response) => {
         setData(response.data.results);
         const myData = data.map((results, index) => ({
           id: results.id,
         }));
         );
         axios({
           method: "get",
           url: `https://api.themoviedb.org/3/list/${myData}?api_key=${API_KEY}`,
         })
           .then((response) => {
             console.log(response);
           })
           .catch((error) => {
             console.error(error);
           });
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }, []);
  return (
    <></>
  );
};

export default MovieList;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're initializing `data` with no value, making it `undefined` when the component mounts.

```
const [data, setData] = useState();
```

Then you're trying to map over `data` after `setData(response.data.results)`. The problem is that `setData` is asynchronous, meaning when `data.map` is called, `data` will still likely be `undefined`

```
setData(response.data.results);
const myData = data.map((results, index) => ({
  id: results.id
}));
```

To solve this, change:

```
setData(response.data.results);
const myData = data.map((results, index) => ({
  id: results.id,
}));
```

to:

```
const { results } = response.data;
setData(results);
const myData = results.map(r => ({ id: r.id }));
```

By doing this, you're directly using the data from the API response, which should always be defined if the response was successful.

**Note**: You should also initialize `data` with an empty array, like so:

```
const [data, setData] = useState([]);
```

This guarantees that you can always do `data.map` in your component without error.